# pyinstaller: change application icon

Tags: python, pyinstaller

First time using pyinstaller, 
I ran pyinstaller appname.py  --icon='myicon.ico'
The icon file is converted using convertico.com and it is at the same directory where I ran pyinstaller

In dist/appname/ directory, the executable appname icon is still not changed.
Did I do something wrong?
The spec file is:

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None

a = Analysis(['appname.py'],
         pathex=['/home/admin/appname'],
         binaries=None,
         datas=None,
         hiddenimports=[],
         hookspath=None,
         runtime_hooks=None,
         excludes=None,
         win_no_prefer_redirects=None,
         win_private_assemblies=None,
         cipher=block_cipher)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
         cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
      a.scripts,
      exclude_binaries=True,
      name='appname',
      debug=False,
      strip=None,
      upx=True,
      console=True , icon='myicon.ico')
coll = COLLECT(exe,
           a.binaries,
           a.zipfiles,
           a.datas,
           strip=None,
           upx=True,
           name='appname')
```

Comment: Your code worked for me without having to use the `--icon` option. (Windows 7 + pyinstaller 3.2.1). The `--icon` option didn't work on it's own though. Only the spec file definition.

Answer (score 11):

It has worked, just a problem with cached icons. If you move the `.exe` to another folder the icon should change. Just to be sure though rebuild using :

```
pyinstaller --onefile --icon=myicon.ico --clean yourapp.py
```

The `--clean` command cleans the cache and your icon will appear correctly

Comment: One more thing to try is [cleaning the icon cache directly](http://superuser.com/questions/499078/refresh-icon-cache-without-rebooting) in the system.